# C# Buttons with nearly same action

Tags: c#, .net

My question is that I have a label which I call "scratchpad".

Then i have 11 Buttons (numbers 0-9 and . ). Now my solution currently is the following:

(**note**: the dot is not yet implemented)

```
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"0";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"1";

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"2";

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"3";

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"4";

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"5";

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"6";

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"7";

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"8";

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + @"9";
```

Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: let buttons have same event then cast the sender to a Textblock

Comment: If your button has text `0`, `1`, and so on, you can point them to the same action, and then add buttons text got from `sender as Button`

Comment: @Mithgroth OP wants to decrease number of methods, assigned to buttons, how should you do that with loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each button has the corresponding number as caption, you can assign the same handler to all the buttons at design time

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;
  label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + btn.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Event binding part, in your form load add all the event to the button.

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn0.Click += digitClicked;
    btn1.Click += digitClicked;
    btn2.Click += digitClicked;
    btn3.Click += digitClicked;
    btn4.Click += digitClicked;
    btn5.Click += digitClicked;
    btn6.Click += digitClicked;
    btn7.Click += digitClicked;
    btn8.Click += digitClicked;
    btn9.Click += digitClicked;
}
```

And use [mnieto's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022638/6560478)

```
private void digitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    txtLogin.Text += btn.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use btn.Text, I would use the Tag property of the button to strore the final string 0, 1 ..... , 9 and the dot.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    label_scratchpad.Text = label_scratchpad.Text + (string)button.Tag;
}
```